# Script to convert all XIBs to the new Xcode 5 XML format

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, ibtool

I need to convert all the xibs in my app from the older 4.x XML format to the Xcode 5 format.

I can do this manually by opening all the xibs in my app, for each language (which amounts to 170+ xibs...).
Or I could use the `ibtool` from Apple which does it for me in CLI.

I tried this:

```
find . -name "*.xib" -exec ibtool {} --upgrade --write {} \;
```

But it only works for XIBs that are in the directory, not for the subdirectories (typically my language-specific xibs..).

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Your script worked perfectly for me and included all subdirectories, so problem likely exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

find . -name *.xib | xargs -t -I $0 ibtool $0 --upgrade --write $0